# How do I get a Door No Pattern?

Tags: regex, html

I'm using the code

```
pattern="#?[0-9]+[/]?[0-9]+"
```

Valid Inputs should be

```
3, #742, #742/53, 234/23
```

And Invalid Inputs should be

```
#, 3#, 742/#45, 742/53#, #742/#53
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zajqD/167/

Comment: Try `#?[0-9]+(?:/[0-9]+)?` if your only issue is that the 1-digit input is not allowed with your regex. Note that *Its not working properly* is not a proper issue description, it makes the whole question unclear.

Comment: Thank You..... I'll change the question

Answer (score 2):

Because you have two `[0-9]+`s, your pattern only matches door numbers with at least two digits. You need to group the slash and second number with the `?` quantifier, rather than just the slash:

```
pattern="#?[0-9]+([/][0-9]+)?"
```

You also may want to "anchor" your pattern, though this should already be the case by HTML5 standards.

```
pattern="^#?[0-9]+([/][0-9]+)?$"
```

Comment: No need to use `^` and `$`, the pattern is used inside the `pattern` attribute. Also, no need placing `/` into a character class.

Comment: I believe the HTML5 standard does say the pattern is already anchored, so you're correct. However I've also read that in practice, only the start is anchored. Not sure if that's changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^#?\d+(?:\/\d+)?(?![\/\d#])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yB3nE6/1)

**Explanation:**
`^`: Start of string or start of line depending on multiline mode
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`\d`: One digit from 0 to 9 [sample](https://regex101.com/r/mN1jN0/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)
`(?: … )`: Non-capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bU9dN1/1)
`(?!…)`: Negative lookahead [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bI9fA5/1)